# How to update an immer draft via path as string?

Tags: javascript, immer.js

I want to update an deeply nested value using [immer.js](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/example-setstate) I'm looking for a generic solution, where the path to value comes as string. Is there a way to send the path to the value as string and update in the draft?

```
const data = { colors: [{id: 1, name: red}] }

const path = "colors.0.name"
const nextValue = "dark red"


 produce((draft) => {

        draft ... name= "dark red"  // via generic path set the value

 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lodash.set`

```js
import { set } from 'lodash';
const data = { colors: [{id: 1, name: red}] }

const path = "colors.0.name"
const nextValue = "dark red"

const nextData = produce((draft) => {
      set(draft, path, nextValue);
});
```